# windows.onload function runs faster than the element is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have make a website to check if a certain checkbox is checked when the page is loaded
i write the below codes

```
window.onload = function () {
   if ($(.myCheckBox).is(":checked")){
      //do somethin
    } else {
      // do another thing
    }
}
```

But it always go to another thing even the check box is checked when the page is loaded
is it onload function run faster than it can detect the value?

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve] that actually reproduces the problem. We can't see what is wrong when (a) you don't provide HTML and (b) the code you've provided **doesn't** "go to another thing" because there's a syntax error that prevents it from running at all. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

i mean you can like that;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checked=$(checkboxSelector).is(':checked')
if(checked){
//bla bla bla
}
else{
//bla bla bla
}
```

so it will work when the page is ready